# An utility for displaying key pressed in screen like OSX/macOS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I saw a lot of videos/gif like the above displaying the pressed keys in screen. Is there any alternative for windows/linux?

[image: Key combination popup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool displayed on the image is [Keycastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr).
KeyCastr, an open-source keystroke visualizer.

Comment: I don't know why I haven't seen this answer until now.

Comment: OP asked about alternatives for windows/linux not about tool on screencast. I'm not sure why this is not only answer, but accepted one. IMHO should be comment only (welcomed one).

Answer (score 4):

According to [AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/software/keycastr/?license=opensource) most favorite choice for Windows is [Carnac](http://carnackeys.com/).

On Linux, most mentioned (and probably only) options are [screenkey](https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/screenkey/) and [key-mon](https://github.com/critiqjo/key-mon).

### key-mon

[key-mon](https://github.com/critiqjo/key-mon) is more similar to screencast in your question. It can optionally display mouse click status. It have multiple themes and visual settings.

[image]

### screenkey

[screenkey](https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/screenkey/) works difOheferently then your screencast. It simply displays all key presses in one long stream of text in configurable area. It can't display status of modifiers (`Ctrl`, `Shift`), it simply handle them as any other key press.

[image]